# Add a title tag with jquery based on each image name

Tags: jquery, title

I want to use jquery to add a title tag to the class ls-thumb-active, I got it to to that with this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
tooltip = "mouseover";

$('.ls-thumb-active').attr('title', tooltip);

$('.displaytitle').html($('.ls-thumb-active').attr('title'));
});//]]>  

</script>
```

The problem is, I want it to display the actual img name as the tooltip variable without the .jpg at the end.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could take out the ".jpg" part of the image name with something like the following, that will allow you to strip any extension after the name of what are you getting:

```
var imageName = imageElementYouAreGettingSomewhere.src;
imageName = imageName.substr(0, imageName.lastIndexOf('.'));

$('.displaytitle').attr('title', imageName );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by "splitting" your img name. So let's say the var image is your image name, something like this:

```
var image = 'something_unusual.jpg';
```

You can get the image name like this:

```
var image_name = image.split('.')[0];
```

Then, of course, you add it the same way you did first:

```
$('.ls-thumb-active').attr('title', image_name);
```

Note that i use the method "split", which split you image name by the caracter "." so if the image, for some reason, as a "." in his name, this might break.  You can also substring, splice, etc, using the index of the last dot. But in that example, if there's not dot in the image name, its gonna work perfectly no matter what the file extension is.
hope this helped.

Comment: What if the image name has a `.`? Say `new.image.jpg`. This doesn't work. *ps: I removed the downvote!*

Comment: hehe thanks for removing the downvote.  As you can see, i thought of it myself as soon as i posted the answer. substr would fit perfectly, taking the index of the last dot. Or you could .split('.'), then '.pop()' (removes last array element) and then '.join('.')'! Thats y i love javascript! A million solutions are available ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is required for every image, you need to iterate over all the images and set the `title` attribute.

```
$('.ls-thumb-active').each(function() {
    var imgName = $(this).attr('src').split('.')[0];
    $(this).attr('title', imgName );
});
```

Comment: You can even do this just with `attr`. See when is `each` used, as it is a costly function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the extension would be either:

- .jpg
- .png
- .gif

You can use substring to cut four characters at the end and add to the title.

```
$('.ls-thumb-active').attr('title', substr(tooltip, 0, strlen(tooltip) - 4));
```

Comment: I think it will be safer to use split method on point character "." and to remove the last part of the obtained array

Comment: what if the extension is `.jpeg` ?

Comment: Ha ha... Didn't think of it!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    tooltip = "mouseover";
    thumActive = $('.ls-thumb-active'); // Cached object
    // Get the source name of the image
    thumbImageSrc = $('.target-of-the-image').attr("src");
    // To slice from the last '/' if there is no '/' then slice from the very start
    thumbImageNameFirstSlice = ( thumbImageSrc.lastIndexOf( '/' ) ? thumbImageSrc.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1 : 0 );
    // And will slice to the last '.'
    thumbImageName = thumbImageSrc.slice( thumbImageNameFirstSlice, thumbImageSrc.lastIndexOf( '.' ) );
    // Your code =)
    thumActive.attr('title', tooltip);
    // Assign the name to the '.displaytitle'
    $('.displaytitle').html( thumbImageName );
});
</script>
```

There is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Np6FG/1/